# How to associate an uploaded picture to a models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I allow users to upload a photo. This photo is stored using paperclip. The model that I use to upload and store the photo is called Upload.

```
# Table name: uploads
#
#  id                 :integer         not null, primary key
#  created_at         :datetime
#  updated_at         :datetime
#  photo_file_name    :string(255)
#  photo_content_type :string(255)
#  photo_file_size    :integer
#  photo_updated_at   :datetime
#
```

have a model that I wish to link to the uploaded photo. It is called Message.

```
Table name messages
#  content            :string(255)
#  upload_id               :string(255)
#  created_at         :datetime
#  updated_at         :datetime
```

I want to use the upload_id to link the image to the message model.

However this means the association will be as follows

```
Message

belongs_to :upload


Upload

has_one :message
```

This seems a bit strange. To add more to the description I will also upload files for other models such as User.  So I really would like to store the upload id in the table for each model that uses an upload.

Then how can I access the upload from an instance of a message

`@message.upload_id.upload`?
`@user.upload_id.upload?`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct your models classes:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :upload
end

class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :message
end
```

Create a migration to add a field `message_id` into uploads table.

And then use `@message.upload` to access your upload model associated with the message.

Comment: So I will need to update my uploads table when I save my message to include the message_id correct?

Comment: I just realized I can't do this because I need to use the uploads for other models. Say a user model as well. Ideally what I want is to store the id of the upload in the table of the model. That way I keep all of the uploads in one place and can get them from the id in the model.

Comment: Then use polymorphic associations: `Upload belongs_to :uploadable, :polymorphic => true` and `Message has_one :upload, :as => :uploadable`

Comment: Thanks Hck. That is starting to make sense. Then the foreign key in the Uploads table would be?

Comment: You need to add `t.integer :uploadable_id` and `t.string  :uploadable_type` to your uploads table

Comment: Thank Hck Will do. Just one thing. I save the upload before I have these model objects. So I am guessing that when I save say Message I must also update the upload as @user.upload.update_attributes(:uploadable_id => @user.id, :uploadable_type => 'user') correct?

Comment: I understand based on your answer from my other question. I will do @user.new. @user.upload = @upload. @user.save.